# Comparing Int Values from Different Classes- Swift Sheep part 2

Tags: class, swift, sprite-kit

Following my previous question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863229/skspritenode-does-not-have-member-named-how-to-access-a-variable-declared-in/28864008#28864008)), I created sheepNode Class to hold an int value. Still new to Swift and how classes are declared, but this class is in the same GameScene.swift file outside of *class GameScene: SKScene{all my gameplay code}*

```
class SheepNode: SKSpriteNode
{
    var sheepValue:Int = 0
}
```

Here's the portion of code that checks for collisions. When checking it sheep.sheepValue is equal to the current equation, this never seems to work.

```
func checkCollisions() {
        var hitSheep: [SheepNode] = []
        enumerateChildNodesWithName("sheep") { node, _ in

        let sheep = node as SheepNode

        if CGRectIntersectsRect(sheep.frame, self.sandman.frame) {

        if sheep.sheepValue == self.equation {
            hitSheep.append(sheep)
            }
        }
```

Setting a breakpoint, I found that sheepValue is still always zero. I double checked this by setting my *self.equation = 0*, and the code works like it should.

**My Attempts to Fix**

1.) In my *spawnSheep function* inside *class GameClass: SKScene*, I changed

```
var sheepValue: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(12))+1)
```

to

```
let sheepValue = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(12))+1)
```

2.) I tried setting the sheepValue in my class sheepNode:

```
class SheepNode: SKSpriteNode
{
//    var sheepValue:Int = 0
   var sheepValue:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(12))+1)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so my third attempt worked! I hope this will help some newbies out there.

My thought process for **sheepValue** was that it's a property of *class sheepNode*. Therefore, when I'm accessing it in a different class that points to that class, I should treat it as a property of my sheep object, which inherits from sheepNode:

```
 sheep.sheepValue = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(12))+1)
```

I'm not sure how to explain in technical terms, but I had to add **"sheep."** to point to the **sheepValue** of *class sheepNode.*